# Reading textfile on server, clientside (JS, Ajax?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, text-files, client-side

I want to read a specific character in a textfile, so I basically want a function where if I write `function getLetter(3)`, it will return the third letter, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you using javascript code to do this?
provide more information like parts of your code..

Comment: @Sudheesh — The question title and the tags say so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you should at least show what you've tried in your question to get an answer on StackOverflow, but I'm feeling generous this morning.

Try this:

```
function getLetter(index) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'my_text_file.txt',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(text) {
            var letter = text.substring(index, 1);
            // do something with letter here...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and simple answer. And yeah i probably should have provided some code, but I have just tried numerous scripts that I didn't really understand, thanks again!

Comment: well thought and +1 for a simple answer

Answer (score 0):

Get the file with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) then get the character with [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).